# Counting average from random numbers from 0 to 1

Tags: c, random, average

I finally got code that's giving me random floats from 0 to 1. 
My code looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
{
srand((int)time(NULL));

int N=10;

float a = 1.0;
for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    printf("%f\n", ((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX)) * a);

return 0;
}
```

Now, I need to make program that will give me the average from given numbers for 10<=N<=10000, but im out of ideas how to make it works. Any ideas?

Comment: Before printing, store them and sum them up.

Comment: I smell the taste of C, not C++.

Comment: Out of curiosity why the multiplication by `a` (1.0)?

Comment: @ringø 100% sure it's redundant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the 'a' variable as temporary storage and summation for the floats.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
{
srand((int)time(NULL));

int lowerLimit = 10 + 1, upperLimit = 10000;
//generates random number between 10 and 10000, if needed
int N =  lowerLimit + rand() % (upperLimit - lowerLimit);

/* 'a' variable was not needed in previous*/
float a, sum = 0.0;
for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
    a = ((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX));
    sum += a;
    printf("Float %i = %f\n", i,a);
}
printf("Average = %f\n", sum/N);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before printing, store them and sum them up.

```
int main()
{
srand((int)time(NULL));

int N=10;

float a = 1.0f, r, sum = 0.0f;
for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
    r = ((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX)) * a;
    printf("%f\n", r);
    sum += f;
}
printf("sum = %f\n", sum / N);

return 0;
}
```